# PHP: Caching system creates an extra 404 error file

Tags: php, caching, http-status-code-404

I have a caching system on my php website.
It works like a charm, but whenever a cache file is created, an extra cache file is generated from the 404 page as well.

Example: I visit page-2, caching system detects that a new cache-file needs to be created. It creates the file for page-2 (and will serve it to other people late), but also a file for the 404 page.

Question: why is the 404 cache-page created?

I tried to find out why, but I am stuck now ...

This is code from my header include:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];

$cachefile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlpage = $cachefile;
$cachefile = md5($cachefile).".html";

    if (!empty($param1) ){$cachetime = 86400;}
    elseif (!empty($param2) ){$cachetime = 86400;}
    elseif (!empty($param3) ){$cachetime = 86400;}
    elseif ($page == 'random' ){$cachetime = 0;}
    else {$cachetime = 60;}

$cachefileloc = __DIR__ . '/../_cache/' .$cachefile;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
    if (file_exists($cachefileloc) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefileloc)) {
        include($cachefileloc);
        exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
<my html-output starts here>
```

This is the code from my footer include:

```
<?php
// Cache the contents to a file
$cached = fopen(__DIR__ . '/../_cache/' .$cachefile, "w");
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

Any thoughts on this issue?

extra information: 
- the 404 page is ALWAYS created AFTER it has created the cache file.
- the 404 page is NOT ALWAYS created, looks like a googlebot visit is not creating a 404.

My .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.EXAMPLE.com/404.php

###################################################
# Turn the RewriteEngine on.                      #
###################################################
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(/)$ /index.php?p= [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?contact/?$ /index.php?p=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?aboutus/?$ /index.php?p=aboutus [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?links/?$ /index.php?p=links [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?searchresults/?$ /index.php?p=searchresults [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?contactmail/?$ /index.php?p=mailing [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?random/?$ /index.php?p=random [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?recent/?$ /index.php?p=recent [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?trends/?$ /index.php?p=trends [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?cookies/?$ /index.php?p=cookies [L]
RewriteRule ^bam/([^/\.]+)/?$ /artists.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^bam/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /artists.php?a=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^browse/([^/\.]+)/?$ /browse.php?l=$1 [L]
```

Comment: so the first call on page-2 there is no actuall "physicaly" page till the Cache generates one?

Comment: @KikiTheOne Yes, or the existing cache file has expired.

Comment: my guess is. when u first load the page. ist not there -> 404 will be generated -> and reloaded and then the page is there cause it was generated. if this makes sense to u somehow

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue. Pages are already there and rewritten.

Comment: so u have Access to the Server auth.log ? there u can see what was executed in which order. maybe this helps to find it

Comment: Check the logs and/or the network tab on your browser dev tools, you probably have a favicon request creating that 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the issue myself!

It was an import of a css-file into a css-file. The imported file does not exist. The apache server log logged no error, because it logged a 302 redirection to the 404 file ...

So, when I saw the pattern of a 302 redirect just before the 404-file being logged, I discovered the import that was wrong.

End of the story: 302 redirects of fishy files that don't exist leads to weird 404 errors :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that query strings are passed to the 404 handler script as well, which results in the generation of a new cache file. To test whether that's indeed the case:

```
//$cachefile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cachefile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
$urlpage = $cachefile;
$cachefile = md5($cachefile).".html";
```

Comment: I don't have query strings in my url's. At least not directly. I added my .htaccess file above, maybe it helps to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the browser is loading a resource from your server. Check if the 404 page came from the favicon.ico resource for example. Else try putting this in your '404.php' file and check your cache for the original url.

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion. The 404 page shows the var_dump now, but it just shows the url from the original page. I will check for other resourses. Favicon is in place btw ;)

Comment: All resources are there.